# Failing to enable includes | apache2

Tags: server, 20.04, apache2, webserver

I'm trying to enable `includes` on a specific URI through Apache2, but I'm getting `an error occurred while processing this directive`:

[image]

My `/magic/index.html` URI is located at `/var/www/html/magic/index.html`:

[image]

..., the `includes` folder is at `/var/www/html/magic/includes`

[image]

...and my conf at `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/magic.conf`:

[image]

`foo.html` and `bar.html` just contain a string of text like `this is the foo include`. I tried surrounding the strings with `<p>` tags also, but got the same error.

[image]

I've tried multiple options for the path on the `virtual` tag of the HTML files, and moving the `includes` folder to `/var/www/html/`, but I always get the same error. I'm open to try any possibility that you guys my suggest though.

Thanks a lot for the help!

**EDIT:**

When changing the `Location` to `/var/www/html/magic`, the includes are not recognized:

[image]

1.
[image]

2.
[image]

Comment: Your `Location` path is incomplete. `/magic/` is not the same as `/var/www/html/magic`. I’m also not sure what you’re trying to do. Is the goal to have the content of your `includes` directory used as part of a template that gets output with the requested HTML file? 

Comment: I changed the `Location` as suggested but the includes are not recognized. I added an edit on the post with the screenshot of what I get. As for what I'm trying to do, it's exactly what you wrote: to get the content of `includes/` on `magic/index.html` (I'm learning how to use apache)  @matigo

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the images of your configuration and files, there are a few things you may want to check:

1. Is `mod_includes` enabled for Apache?

   ```
   sudo a2enmod includes
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to restart/reload Apache afterwards: `sudo service apache2 restart`</sup>
2. Are the files for inclusion properly readable by Apache?

   ```
   sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/magic
   ```
3. Have you configured `AddType` and `AddOutputFilter` in the virtual host configuration file?

   ```
   <Directory /var/www/concept>
       Options +Includes

       ...

       AddType text/html .html
       AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .html
   </Directory>
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to restart/reload Apache afterwards: `sudo service apache2 restart`</sup>

So long as these three items are correct, you should be good to go. I've tested this on a fresh Ubuntu Server 20.04 VM running Apache 2.4.41.

Comment: Still the same error. I edited my post and added at the bottom two more screenshots referencing your first and second point. As for the third, I was unsure about where `/var/www/concept` came from since I don't have any stanza with that path on my vhost config file, so I tried different approaches: creating a new Directory with those exact params that you wrote and `/var/www/concept`; I have a Directory with a path of `/var/www/` so I tried adding those options there instead, tried also adding them on `Location`...but none of them did the job